# Accessing an element of a nested object using a variable for the key?

Tags: javascript

Silly example:

```
<script>
var a = {
    'b' : {
        'c' : "success!!"
    }
};
var d = 'b.c';
</script>
```

How could I access `success!!` if I can't go for the obvious solution `a.b.c` or `a['b']['c']`, but instead have to use `d`? I tried `a[d]`, which doesn't seem to do the trick. I also tried to fiddle with `eval()`. Is this even possible?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/442c6xkk/1/

Comment: Well, if you are going to use eval - alert(eval('a.' + d)) :-)

Comment: Using eval for this is just wrong. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really necessary to have the keys in a string separated with a dot, I would use split and reduce:

```
var success = d.split(".").reduce(function (obj, key) {
  return obj[key];
}, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting

```js
var a = {
    'b' : {
        'c' : "success!!"
    }
};
var d = 'b.c';

var splat = d.split('.');

console.log(a[splat[0]][splat[1]]);
```